# Custom Fonts in Visualforce Page (renderas="pdf")

Tags: visualforce, pdf

Trying to use a custom font in my visualforce page (rendered as pdf). I have looked at many conflicting articles saying that the only option are the "limited" fonts supported, whereas others say that you can add the css as a static resource and reference (https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F000000096dcIAA   bottom comment).

Does anyone know if this is possible/had success with custom fonts before?

Comment: did you try ? Often that's quite a good way to discover what's possible and what's not.

Comment: No I haven't  tried it, didn't want to waste company time on a wild goose chase. It's just that I was getting very mixed responses when researching ("it's not possible / it should be possible / try using css as a static resource, etc.). Thanks though

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The current v31.0 "official" line is that there is a limited set of fonts available.

> ## Fonts Available When Using Visualforce PDF Rendering

> Visualforce PDF rendering supports a limited set of fonts. Use the following font names to ensure that PDF output renders as you expect.
> The fonts available when you’re rendering a page as a PDF are as follows. The first listed font-family value for each typeface is the recommended choice.

> - **Typeface**
> - **Style font-family Value to Use (Font Synonyms)**

> - Arial Unicode MS
> - Arial Unicode MS
> - Helvetica
> - sans-serif
> - SansSerif
> - Dialog
> - Times
> - serif
> - Times
> - Courier
> - monospace
> - Courier
> - Monospaced
> - DialogInput

> **Note**

> - These rules apply to server-side PDF rendering. You might see different results when viewing pages in a web browser.
> - Text styled with any value besides those listed above receives the default font style, Times. This means that, ironically, while Helvetica’s synonyms render as Helvetica, using “Helvetica” for the font-family style renders as Times. We recommend using “sans-serif”.
> - Arial Unicode MS is the only multibyte font available, providing support for the extended character sets of languages that don’t use the Latin character set.

[Source - Fonts Available When Using Visualforce PDF Rendering](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_supported_fonts.htm)

Note also that [there is talk of a new and improved PDF rendering engine in the works](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/46517/102). This may give you better font options, but is only in closed pilot last time I checked.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the PDF generation in Salesforce is based on [Flying Saucer](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/), the Flying Saucer [FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/wiki/FAQPDF) includes an example of how to embed a custom font:

```
@font-face {
        font-family: "UbuntuMono";
        src: url("UbuntuMono-R.ttf");
        -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
        -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H; 
}

* {
        font-family: "UbuntuMono";
}
```

which suggests it is possible. You would need to use a public URL for the font or a static resource URL.

But I have not tried it.

**PS**

Just spent 30 minutes trying to get this to work for a [Google font](https://www.google.com/fonts) and while it works well for the HTML output I could not get it to work for PDF output. So either by design or accident **it looks like this does not work in Salesforce**.

Comment: I've [had a similar thought before](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/38527/102), but never actually tried it in practice. Thinking about it more, I'd be surprised if the Salesforce PDF rendering engine would pull in a random font resource from the internet. How would they know they could trust the URL?

Comment: I am having the same use case and want to use custom font on pdf page, while running the page in html mode, it works, but in `renderAs="pdf"`, not working.
My code is this
`@font-face {
          font-family: "FuturaBT-Light";
          src: url('{!URLFOR($Resource.FuturaFont, 'Futura_Corporate.ttf')}')  format('truetype');
        }`

Comment: "The font used on the page must be available on the Visualforce PDF rendering service. Web fonts aren’t supported." [Visualforce PDF Rendering Considerations and Limitations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_considerations.htm)

Comment: Unfortunately that Salesforce website Visualforce PDF Rendering Considerations and Limitations link is no longer working.