# Get base64 of image from rich text field

Tags: apex, visualforce, images, image-formula

My question is about rendering image using its base64 instead of src attribute. I have a rich text field where users can attach images. I am displaying these images in a visualforce page. How can I render the images with base64 instead of regular src attribute?

Here's my apex code:

```
public List<SObject> getResults () {
    Id id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    List<SObject> results = [SELECT Id, 
                                    Name,
                                    Screenshot__c
                                    FROM myCustomObject__c 
                                    WHERE parent__c = :id];
    return results;
}
```

And here's my visualforce:

```
<apex:repeat var="v" value="{! results }">
      <div class="styleclass">
          {! v.Name}
      </div>
      <h3>Screenshot</h3>
      <div class="styleclass">
          <apex:outputField value="{! v.Screenshot__c}"/>
      </div>
</apex:repeat>
```

The above visualforce snippet renders the images, giving me something like this:

> `<p><img src="https://mydomain.documentforce.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=imageid&amp;feoid=someid&amp;refid=someid" alt="myimage.png"></img></p>`

Instead of this, how can I get base64 of an image? Something like this:

```
<img alt="my image" src="data:image/png;base64,{base64dataofImage}/>
```

Appreciate your help on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its better to save base64 encoded value of `Screenshot__c` field in new field created in `myCustomObject__c` object so that you can easily get encoded value and pass to visualforce page.

For encoding Screenshot__c use below code and do a mass update all records:

```
EncodingUtil.Base64Encode(myCustomObject__c.Screenshot__c);
```

After that update your query as

```
List<SObject> results = [SELECT Id, 
                                Name,
                                Screenshot__c,
                                Encoded_Screenshot__c //update field api name accordingly
                         FROM myCustomObject__c 
                         WHERE parent__c = :id];
```

Update visualforce code as

```
<img alt="my image" src="data:image/png;base64,{!v.Encoded_Screenshot__c}/>
```

Or another approach you can implement is store your screenshot__c as attachment for myCustomObject__c record and implement as discussed here.

[Display Base64 data on a Visualforce page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005941&type=1)

[Render blob image in visualforce page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21508/render-blob-image-in-pdf-using-visualforce)

---

**Edit:**

You cannot query attachment body field in join queries. You need another soql to get that.

```
List<SObject> results = [SELECT Id, 
                                    Name,
                                    Screenshot__c,
                                    (SELECT Id, Name FROM Attachments)
                             FROM myCustomObject__c 
                             WHERE parent__c = :id];
```

Get Attachments in separate query in a Map.

```
Map<ID, Attachment> attMap = [Select Id, Body, Parent.Type FROM Attachment WHERE Parent.Type = 'myCustomObject__c'];
```

In vf page:

```
{!attMap[v.Attachments[0].Id].Body}
```

Comment: thanks for answering! The problem with the second approach I am having is I am not sure how to get the attachment into a SOQL query and reference the attachment in a merge field. Could you please help with that part?

Comment: @Illusion Updated my answer.

Comment: @Illusion how did you manage to get the base64 format of the image from richtext field ?